# Any idea how to calculate median value of each part of column

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have a data like this:

```
111 5
111 6
111 1
222 8
222 9
222 1
222 3
555 9
555 7
555 6
```

and for each value of `$1`, I want to get the median value of all the values of `$2` for that `$1` if possible using AWK .

desired output:

```
111 5 5
111 6 5
111 1 5
222 8 5.5
222 9 5.5
222 1 5.5
222 3 5.5
555 9 7
555 7 7
555 6 7
```

Where 5 is the median value of 5, 6 and 1 (the values for `$1` == `111`), 5.5 the median value of 8, 9, 1 and 3, etc.

Comment: I don’t understand the notion of a median value of $2… I know a median value of a list of values (median of 1 3 6 7 8 is 6). Could you detail your calculus.

Comment: There's a potential bug that could appear in a solution if you can have multiple occurrences of the same 2nd field for a given 1st field (e.g. if in GNU awk we initially stored the input as `vals[$1][$2]`) so you should include a case like that in your sample input/output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using any sort+awk in any shell on every unix box:

```
$ cat tst.awk
$1 != prev { if (NR>1) prt(); prev=$1 }
{ vals[++cnt] = $2 }
END { prt() }

function prt(   i,med) {
    med = (vals[int((cnt+1)/2)] + vals[int((cnt/2)+1)]) / 2
    for (i=1; i<=cnt; i++) {
        print prev, vals[i], med
    }
    cnt = 0
}
```

```
$ sort -k1,1n -k2,2n file | awk -f tst.awk
111 1 5
111 5 5
111 6 5
222 1 5.5
222 3 5.5
222 8 5.5
222 9 5.5
555 6 7
555 7 7
555 9 7
```

The above stores all of the `$2` values for the current `$1` in an array called `vals[]`, then when the `$1` value changes or the end of file is reached it calls `prt()` which figures out the median value for that array, stores it in a variable named `med` and then in a loop prints the `$1` plus all of the associated `$2`s and `med`.

The above re-orders the lines for output. If that's an issue we can decorate the lines first to save their original order, then do the above sort+awk, then sort again back to the original order and finally undecorate.

If you have GNU awk and your key values are already sorted then you could call `asort()` inside the `prt()` function and then you don't need to call `sort` before `awk`. If nothing is sorted you could store everything in arrays then sort in the END section. But just calling `sort` first as shown is clearest, simplest, most efficient, and most portable.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming the data is already sorted lexicographically on the first column and that you are using a shell that understands process substitutions with `<(...)`:

```bsh
$ join file <( datamash -W groupby 1 median 2 <file )
111 5 5
111 6 5
111 1 5
222 8 5.5
222 9 5.5
222 1 5.5
222 3 5.5
555 9 7
555 7 7
555 6 7
```

This performs a relational JOIN operation on the first field of the file with the result of the command

```bsh
datamash -W groupby 1 median 2 <file
```

This command calculates the median for each set of values in the second field, grouped by the values in the first field. With the `-W` option, we make GNU `datamash` treat the input as whitespace-delimited.

The result of that operation is

```
111     5
222     5.5
555     7
```

Joining this to the original data on the first field gives you your wanted result.

If the data isn't already sorted on the first field:

```bsh
join <( sort -k 1,1n file ) <( datamash -s -W groupby 1 median 2 <file )
```

If you want to ensure that lines having the same first field are not reordered relative to each other, then make sure that the `sort file` command uses a *stable* sort algorithm. Most `sort` implementations allow you to do this by using the non-standard `-s` option.

---

For a shell without process substitution:

- Data is sorted:

  ```bsh
  datamash -W groupby 1 median 2 <file | join file -
  ```
- Data needs sorting:

  ```bsh
  sort -o file.sorted -k 1,1n file
  datamash -W groupby 1 median 2 <file.sorted | join file.sorted -
  rm -f file.sorted
  ```

Answer (score 2):

Using GNU awk for the asort() function and regardless of if your data is sorted or not but require to process the input file twice; at first time processing we group each Id values into one and after that we calculate the median for each group and at the second time of the processing file we are just printing their calculated median as the last column from the *`id`* array:

```
awk -v sep=, 'NR==FNR{ id[$1]=($1 in id ? id[$1] sep : "") $2; next }
     FNR==1 {
                for(x in id){
                    ln=split(id[x], tmp, sep); asort(tmp)
                    id[x]=(ln%2? tmp[int(ln/2)+1]: (tmp[ln/2]+ tmp[ln/2+1])/2 )
                }
            }
{ print $0, id[$1] }' infile infile
```